# Error compiling bootstrap scss with grunt and node-scss

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, sass, gruntjs

I'm getting the following error when trying to compile bootstrap scss.  I retrieved the scss file using `bower install bootstrap-sass-official`.

```
Warning: bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/stylesheets/boot
strap/glyphicons:17: error: non-terminal statement or declaration must end with
';'
 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I'm using node-sass 0.8.6 and grunt-sass 0.8.1

Here is the snippet of sass where the error occurs

```
15 @font-face {
16  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
17  src: url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.eot'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.eot'));
18  src: url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.eot?#iefix'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.eot?#iefix')) format('embedded-opentype'),
19   url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.woff'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.woff')) format('woff'),
20   url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.ttf'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.ttf')) format('truetype'),
21   url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.svg##{$icon-font-svg-id}'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.svg##{$icon-font-svg-id}')) format('svg');
22 }
```

Comment: you are missing `;` somewhere in the stylesheets

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is on NetBeans:

I got a similar error using Bootstrap SASS files in NetBeans, both in the _glyphicon.scss file and the mixin file _image.scss. Your solution of saving the if statements in variables fixed the error in both cases.

E.g.

```
@mixin img-retina($file-1x, $file-2x, $width-1x, $height-1x) {
   $image-if1: if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-image-path("#{$file-1x}"), "#{$file-1x}");
  background-image: url($image-if1);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the if statements out of the url definition and defined separate variables for them and it worked.